# What exactly gets caught in an extended try-with-resources statement?

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch, try-with-resources

In the following block of code:

```
try ( /* resources declaration */ ) {
    // some dangerous code
} catch (Exception e) {
    // error handling and reporting
}
```

What would happen if *both* the code inside the `try` block and the automatic `close()` statement threw exceptions? Which one would get caught in the `catch` block? Both of them? Only one of them? If so, which one?

Furthermore, what if the `try` is successful but the `close` is not? Would the catch block be entered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from the JLS section [14.20.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1):

> In a basic try-with-resources statement that manages a single resource:
>
> - If the initialization of the resource completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value `V`, then the try-with-resources statement completes abruptly because of a `throw` of the value `V`.
> - If the initialization of the resource completes normally, and the `try` block completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value `V`, then:
>
>   - If the automatic closing of the resource completes normally, then the try-with-resources statement completes abruptly because of a `throw` of the value `V`.
>   - If the automatic closing of the resource completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value `V2`, then the try-with-resources statement completes abruptly because of a `throw` of value `V` with `V2` added to the suppressed exception list of `V`.
> - If the initialization of the resource completes normally, and the `try` block completes normally, and the automatic closing of the resource completes abruptly because of a throw of a value `V`, then the try-with-resources statement completes abruptly because of a `throw` of the value `V`.

This means that if both the code inside the `try` block and the automatic `close()` statement throw an exception, the `catch` part will handle the exception thrown by the `try` block, with the exception thrown by `close()` in the [suppressed exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7849416/1743880).

Also, this means that if the `try` block is successful but the automatic `close()` fails, the `catch` will sill be executed and the catched exception will be the exception thrown by `close()`.

---

Here's a test to verify this behaviour:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // try block fails and close() fails
        try (T t = new T()) {
            throw new Exception("thrown by try part");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getSuppressed()[0].getMessage());
        }

        // try block is successful but close() fails
        try (T t = new T()) {
            //
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class T implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("thrown by close");
    }
}
```

This code will print

```
thrown by try part
thrown by close
thrown by close
```

meaning that the catched exception was the exception thrown by the try part of the code for the first part. For the second part, the catched exception was indeed the exception thrown by `close()`.

Answer (score -1):

The exception thrown inside the try block is thrown to the outside world.

While with the try-catch-finally the exception thrown from the finally block would be propagated up the call stack.

```
InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("file.txt");

        int data = input.read();
        while(data != -1){
            System.out.print((char) data);
            data = input.read();
        }
    } finally {
        if(input != null){
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

In this case, if an exception occurs in both the try block and the finally block(when the InputStream is closed), the the last one is thrown, even if the exception thrown from the try block would probably be more relevant to propagate.

```
try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.txt")) {

        int data = input.read();
        while(data != -1){
            System.out.print((char) data);
            data = input.read();
        }
    }
```

While in this case if an exception occurs in both the try block and the finally block, the first one is propagated

Comment: There's a catch statement that will handle the exceptions thrown by the `try`. I don't know how those exceptions will be thrown to the outside world.

Comment: if the closable resource throws an exception when closed, the exception that occurred in the try block is more relevant, so it's propagated

Comment: Please read the question again, look that OP is clearly stating that **there's a `catch` statement being used**

Comment: The catch will handle the try exception. So what if an exception occurs(in the try-with-resource) when the resource is closed ?