# How to return all errors from an @Transactional marked method?

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I am sorry if that question has been asked before. I am new to Spring framework and I have a practical question about **@Transactional** and a problem that I have.

In a loop, I am inserting some objects into database using JDBC and a SQL stored procedure. Insert may fail for some reason for some/none/all of the objects. If all inserts are without errors ok, otherwise two things have to be done. Firstly all the successful inserts needs to be rolled back, and the list of all the errors must be returned.

So far I have come up with a code that does the rollback, but I cannot figure out how to return an array with the errors.

```
@Transactional
public String[] insertSomeObjects(SomeObject[] some){
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(SomeObject temp:some){
        try{
            jdbcInsertFunction(temp);
        }catch(Exception ex){ // If error occurs, ad it to error list
            String error = createProperErrorMessage(ex);
            errors.Add(error);
        }
    }
    if (errors.size >0){
        // If there are errors, throw exception and roll back
        Throw new Exception
    }
}
```

This code works fine, it inserts all the objects and if any of them fails it rolls back. The problem is that I cannot return the list of errors.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just return errors.toArray();

Comment: and how would you do the rollback in this case?

Comment: Why not put the errors into the exception object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [suppressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849416/what-is-a-suppressed-exception) exceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TransactionRolledbackException {


    TransactionRolledbackException te = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        try{
            //doStuff
            throw new NullPointerException("Exception no:" + i );
        }catch (Exception e) {
            if(te == null){
                te = new TransactionRolledbackException();
            }

            te.addSuppressed(e);
        }


    }


    if(te != null){
        throw te;   
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException
    at chapter4.Exceptionsss.main(Exceptionsss.java:18)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception no:0
        at chapter4.Exceptionsss.main(Exceptionsss.java:15)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception no:1
        at chapter4.Exceptionsss.main(Exceptionsss.java:15)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception no:2
        at chapter4.Exceptionsss.main(Exceptionsss.java:15)
```

Comment: That's actually pretty smooth! Thanks for answering.

Comment: @rob i am glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have come up with a code that does the rollback, but I cannot figure out how to return an array with the errors.

If you are trying to return the errors and all you can do is throw an exception then you can write your own exception that has a `List<String> errors` field in it.  Then you would do:

```
throw new ExceptionWithErrors(cause, errors);
```

When you catch the exception back in the caller then you can call `ewe.getErrors()`.  I tend to not store data in exceptions because I've seen some really bad examples of doing so but in your case, if you are storing error details then this pattern seems like a good one.

A possible problem with this mechanism is that I've had problems when the exiting of the transaction is the thing that causes the rollback.  I've even had problems when I throw an exception but then when the transaction finishes another exception is generated and the first one (with the error context) is lost.