# Difference between suppressedException and cause

Tags: java, exception

I have my own exception, thrown by my class, BrowserException.
It may be because some internal problem, i.e. UnsupporderEncodingException.

Now I have 2 options:

1. Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable exception)
2. Throwable.initCause(Throwable cause)

In exceptions, what is the difference between suppressedException and cause?
When will I prefer to use each of them?

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849416/what-is-a-suppressed-exception and for cause

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A suppressed exception is one which *would* have happened if another exception hadn't occurred. I'm only aware of one case where this happens, which is with a try-with-resources statement. The [JLS (14.20.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) says:

> Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value. An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources. Such an exception is *suppressed* if an exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or the closing of a resource.

So suppose you're trying to write to a file stream on a USB stick, and the USB stick is remove. The `write` call throws an `IOException` - but so does the `close` call, because it's trying to flush a buffer. The original exception from the `write` call will be the one the caller sees, but they'll be able to get at the one thrown by `close` as a suppressed exception.

An exception has a *cause* if it's effectively the result of transforming one exception into another. Suppose you're writing a SQL system that talks to the local file system. Your JDBC driver methods can only throw `SQLException`, so what do you do if your underlying code throws an `IOException` because it can't read from disk? You may want the details of the `IOException` to be visible in the `SQLException`, so you pass that into the constructor of `SQLException` - the `IOException` is the *cause* of the exception.

You're unlikely to ever need to add suppressed exceptions yourself, but creating one exception that's caused by another (typically through the constructor rather than by calling `initCause`) is reasonably common.